# Vb.net System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes throws error when there is space in file name

Tags: vb.net, file

I am using the System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes() method to read a file from the system. Whenever there is a space in the file name it throws a "Could not find a part of the path" error.

I tried adding double quotes to both ends of the path. Then it threw illegal characters in path error.

Also tried replacing space with %20. Threw illegal character error again.

How to overcome this?

My code:

```
Dim fpath = "D:\DOWNLOADED_FILES\Cir 14_2019.pdf"
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fpath)
```

Explorer showing file path:
[image: Explorer showing file path]

Comment: Doesn't happen here.

Comment: Any changes you made?

Comment: Please take a screenshot of explorer showing both the file and the path to it and post it in your question.

Comment: @VisualVincent added screenshot

Comment: Sometimes what appears to be a withespace is not a blank char (Chr(32)). Press F2 on your file, delete the space and reenter a space with the spacebar.

Comment: @Steve Actually my program receives the file from server. So manually editing filename is not feasible.

Comment: I am just trying to pinpoint the problem (if that's the problem).

Comment: @Steve okay.. will do that and update :-)

Comment: @Steve tried. Still the same error. Could not find a part of the path

Comment: Permissions? I would check those as last idea

Comment: @Steve will check that also and update. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you call `Directory.GetFiles` for that folder and see if you get that file name in the results. You can then check each character in it to see whether @VisualVincent was on the right track.

Comment: If you hold down SHIFT and right-click your file in explorer you get an extended context menu where you can select `Copy as path`. Press that and then paste it in your code to see if the behaviour is any different. If it is, post that exact path here so that we can examine it (or use jmcilhinney's suggestion, either way the actual path needs to be checked char-by-char).

Comment: "Could not find a part of the path" does *not* describe a problem with the file name.  It is a complaint about the drive or directory.  The D: drive looks like a mapped drive to a file share named "Work".  Drive letter mappings are a per-user setting, so if you run the program with UAC elevation or with a different account then it won't know what D: means.  Use the UNC name instead, like `\\Server\Work\Downloaded_Files\foo.bar`

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fpath)
```

to:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String.Format("""{0}""", fpath))
```

Comment: OP has already tried that: *I tried adding double quotes to both ends of the path. Then it threw illegal characters in path error.*

Comment: Yes you are right @Andrew Morton. He did "say that", but never showed us that.